# Display images before page loading

Tags: jquery, ajax

does anyone have any idea how can i display the images i'm getting with a success function of an AJAX call, before the page finishes loading.
i have a page that has an AJAX CALL that is getting me from php the last image in a specific folder.
i want the browser to display my images as soon as it gets them before it finishes loading the page because it is running a long duration process and will not stop loading, not untill it finishes the process.
this is what i have done so far

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        sendRequest();

        function sendRequest() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ path('prestaShop_test_get_screenShots') }}",
                success:
                    function (data) {
                        $('#links').append($("<div />", {
                                class: 'gallery',

                            }).append($("<a />", {
                                href: 'assets/screenshots/' + data,
                                title: data

                            }).append($("<img />", {
                                src: 'assets/screenshots/' + data,
                                alt: data,
                                style: 'width:400px ; height: 200px'
                            }))
                            )
                        );
                    },
                complete: function () {
                    // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
                    setInterval(sendRequest, 5000); // The interval set to 5 seconds
                }
            });
        };


</script>
```

when i inspect the code i can see that the image is there but the it is waiting for the browser to finish loading.
because when i stop the loading all the images are displayed at once.

Comment: You can't do this

Comment: I don't understand. what do you want?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

Because ajax request should slower than init a DOM view. But you can try to make a preloader at `onload` event.

Please find and preloader plugin example on [here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/preloader/).

This example is when document (html and it's head) load triggered, will show an overlayed preloader on top. Once the image finished load, the preloader will remove.

Or, you can append an overlay preloader on `onload` event, then add a function to remove the preloader when ajax function end.

Simple example:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
    var preloader = /* preloader code here, with an id (let say #preloader) */;
    $("body").prepend(preloader);
});
/* when first ajax request done */
function sendRequest() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ path('prestaShop_test_get_screenShots') }}",
            success:
                function (data) {
                    $('#links').append($("<div />", {
                            class: 'gallery',

                        }).append($("<a />", {
                            href: 'assets/screenshots/' + data,
                            title: data

                        }).append($("<img />", {
                            src: 'assets/screenshots/' + data,
                            alt: data,
                            style: 'width:400px ; height: 200px'
                        }))
                        )
                    );
                    $("#preloader").remove();
                },
            complete: function () {
                // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
                setInterval(sendRequest, 5000); // The interval set to 5 seconds
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: i think you didn't get exactly what i want .. i have a problem just with displaying the images .. they exist in the page but are not displayed not untill the loading of the page finishes.

Comment: There are no event can do ajax request and let ajax call finish before page load.